# protractor tinymce automated tests

Tags: angularjs, selenium, tinymce, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to test AngularJS tinyMCE with protractor and I keep bumping into problems when trying to send content or do any test on the tinyMCE editor. The environment for testing is `Selenium` with `Jasmine2`

Currently i have:

## HTML

```
<textarea 
    id="page-editor" 
    ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" 
    ng-model="item.description">
</textarea>
```

## Test

```
browser.switchTo().frame('page-editor_ifr');
var body = element(by.id('tinymce'));
body.clear();
body.click();
body.sendKeys('Testing123');
```

The error I get is: `Failed: no such frame` but if I load the page normally the frame is there with the correct ID. Also tried using promise

```
browser.switchTo().frame('page-editor_ifr')
    .then(function() {
        var body = element(by.id('tinymce'));
        body.clear();
        body.click();
        body.sendKeys('Testing123');
    });
```

but with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find that frame first and pass the [element finder](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) to the `switchTo().frame()`:

```
var frame = element(by.id('page-editor_ifr'));
browser.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

Comment: thanks. that did it. I can now select the item though it is too big and returning Failed: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @Blitz well, this is a separate problem. If you need help, consider creating a separate question - share the link here in comments in case. Thanks.